# Amundsen - Unable to load data from S3 to Neptune

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, amazon-neptune

I am facing a problem when loading the data from S3 to Neptune.

Exception: Failed to load csv. Response: {'detailedMessage': 'Unable to connect to s3 endpoint. Provided source = s3://amundsendev/amundsen_data/2022_07_28_17_27_05 and region = us-east-1. Please verify your S3 configuration.', 'code': 'InternalFailureException', 'requestId': '1afc36a9-e5db-433d-9563-d40165069b3a'}

[image]

Really appreciate some help here !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Neptune instances reside within a VPC and do not have native access to the Internet (which includes S3, as S3 is a public facing service).  In order for your Neptune instances to connect to S3, you'll need to deploy an S3 VPC Endpoint in your VPC and associate it with the route table(s) used by your Neptune instances' subnets.

More in the docs here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-IAM.html#bulk-load-tutorial-vpc

Comment: Hi, I am now facing the following error requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='amundsendb.cluster-cyyrbmjrace5.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com', port=8182): Max retries exceeded with url: /loader (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4e66115ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Comment: Can you still reach the /status endpoint for your cluster?  Just a curl to `https://<endpoint>:<port>/status` - that would check the connectivity from wherever you are issuing the request.

Comment: Can i have some help here to overcome S3 endpoint connection issue?

Comment: Happy to assist. Are you still stuck on the `ConnectionError`, as mentioned above?  From where are you issuing the request to the `/loader` API?  Neptune is hosted in a VPC, so you'll need to issue the `/loader` request from within the VPC.  The security group for Neptune will also need to allow network access from wherever you are issuing the request.

Comment: I am good with the issue, able to solve it. Thanks everyone for the kind help.

Comment: @AkhilChakicherla facing same error, can you please tell me how did you solve it.